# Will a tablet with USB 2.0 support USB host mode without the need to root it?

Tags: android, usb

Will a tablet with USB 2.0 in it support USB host mode without the need to root it?

I want to buy the tablet to test my project which involves sending data from my tablet to 8051. Will I need to root the tablet?

Comment: No need...
You can definilety control BT,inernet and USB 
any application can use usb.basicaly they are all IO connections

Comment: i'm trying to send signals from my android tablet to 8051 microcontroller over 8051 ustick(usb support for 8051)...is it a possibility ..if so how will the android device know that 8051 has been connected to it ..since 8051 wont have any device attributes via which i can track it and let my application know that 8051 has been connected to the tablet.

Answer (score 0):

From [the source](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html): USB host mode is supported in Android 3.1 (API level 12). [...] Support for USB host and accessory modes are ultimately dependant on the device's hardware

Some tables still run Android 2.x only, they will not support USB host mode. And some may just not have the USB hardware for Host mode.

A strong hint for USB Host mode would be an A-type USB Port like the ones on PCs and Laptops.

Comment: Thanks a lot ...i ordered the tablet with A type USB port keeping the same thing in mind(since it has the usb port to access a pendrive then it must definitely support USB host mode).

Answer (score 0):

how to interface android and usb midi because while my search on google i found that it is different then regular and difficult and also my 8051 board using midi is not getting detected